# How to write unit test to check database creation

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a sample function as below that receives the database name and creates a new database. I would like to write a unit test for this function. Any idea how to write test case for it? Many thanks.

```
import psycopg2


def create_database(db_name):

    conn = psycopg2.connect(
      database="postgres", user='postgres', password='password', host='127.0.0.1', port= '5432'
    )

    conn.autocommit = True

    #Creating a cursor object using the cursor() method
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    #Preparing query to create a database
    sql = f'''CREATE database {db_name}''';

    #Creating a database
    cursor.execute(sql)
    print("Database created successfully........")

    #Closing the connection
    conn.close()
```

Comment: I don't have a solution but would like to give some keywords to you you should think about. Ask yourself what is a _Unit_? Do you test a unit as a piece of code or as a piece of behavior? There are two big "schools" of unittest: "Classical (Detroid)" and "London". They are not enemies. They can used together depending on the specific use/test-case. I would recommend to take a look into _Unit Testing - Principles, Practices, and Patterns_ (by Vliadimir Khorikov, 2020) to dive deeper into that topic.

Comment: If you really like to test if the database was created (e.g. as a file on the filesystem) that this can't be covered by a **unit** test but by a system test. Your software is not responsible for creating that database file. The database system itself is responsible.

Comment: You can refer to this link - https://medium.com/swlh/python-testing-with-a-mock-database-sql-68f676562461